# Complex XML validation with XSD

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xml-validation

Suppose I have the following XML, how should I update my XSD schema (described below as well) to prevent it's validation?

Basically, for question #3, it looks like its a single choice question as there is only one answer in the  tag. But then there must be at least one  tag inside the  tag otherwise there is no other question available to select but the correct one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<quiz>
  <question><!-- single choice question -->
    <text>Question 1</text>
    <answers>
      <answer>Answer 1</answer>
      <answer>Answer 2</answer>
      <answer>Answer 4</answer>
      <correct>
        <answer>Answer 3</answer>
      </correct>
    </answers>
  </question>
  <question><!-- multiple choice question -->
    <text>Question 2</text>
    <answers>
      <answer>Answer 1</answer>
      <answer>Answer 3</answer>
      <correct>
        <answer>Answer 2</answer>
        <answer>Answer 4</answer>
      </correct>
    </answers>
  </question>
  <question><!-- doesn't make sense. help me prevent this validation -->
    <text>Question 3</text>
    <answers>
      <correct>
        <answer>Some answer</answer>
      </correct>
    </answers>
  </question>
  <question><!-- all answers are correct -->
    <text>Question 4</text>
    <answers>
      <correct>
        <answer>Answer 1</answer>
        <answer>Answer 2</answer>
        <answer>Answer 3</answer>
        <answer>Answer 4</answer>
      </correct>
    </answers>
  </question>
</quiz>
```

Here is the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="quiz">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="question">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="answers">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                     name="answer" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="correct" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="answer"
                           type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your XML shouldn't validate because there is only one answer for the question? If so, your schema already does that. (Your XML is not valid using this schema.)

Comment: You are correct DevNull, the current schema does that. But I have to update the schema to pass the case where all n possible answer choices are correct answers. Now, the updated schema does not work when there is only one answer specified in <correct /> and no where else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the `answer` element (`\question\answers\answer`), should have minOccurs = 1. You originally had this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="answer" type="xs:string" />
```

Change it to this and you'll get the validation you're looking for:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="answer" type="xs:string" />
```

However, if you're looking to validate that the `correct` sequence has more than one `answer` listed when there are no "incorrect" `answer` elements listed in the `answers` sequence - you're out of luck. You cannot do that type of validation using XML schemas.